# Create remove/add action hook for a function within a class in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I try to create a remove_action/add_action hook for an action within a class of a plugin which is as follow (only added some important snippets of the code):

**In the first file is defined:**

```
class Stock_status {
    protected static $instance = null;
    public $stock_product = null;

    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$instance ) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->includes();
        $this->stock_product = new Product();
    }
}
Stock_status::instance();
```

**In the second file is defined:**

```
class Product extends Base {
    public function __construct() {
      add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' , array( $this , 'add_stack_status_in_summary' ) , 15 );
    }
}
```

I was able to use add_action hook as follow to display it on a desired position:

```
add_action( 'astra_woo_shop_price_after', array( new Product, 'add_stack_status_in_summary' ), 20 );
```

But it still appears on the first hook position as well. Can you help how to correctly define it? Thanks.

## Working solution in this case (thanks **@CBroe**):

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array( Stock_status::instance()->stock_product, 'add_stack_status_in_summary' ), 15 );    
add_action( 'astra_woo_shop_price_after', array( Stock_status::instance()->stock_product, 'add_stack_status_in_summary' ), 15 );
```

Comment: _"I was able to use add_action hook as follow"_ - where exactly, what is the context of this? When you use `array( new Product, 'add_stack_status_in_summary' )` for the callback parameter, you are creating a new instance of Product at this point - currently unable to tell, whether that actually makes sense to begin with.

Comment: To remove an action, you need to call `remove_action` with the _exact_ same value for the callback parameter, and the priority. This means, when inside the Product constructor this was added via `array( $this , 'add_stack_status_in_summary' )`, you need that exact "$this" to be able to remove it again. So if you wanted to do that from within your `Stock_status` class, you should use `$this->stock_product` then, because that is the specific Product instance you created.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for help. Yes, that's what I tried but it does nothing. This is code I tried:

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array( $this->stock_product, 'add_stack_status_in_summary' ), 15 );`

Comment: Is it your `Stock_status` class, that created the original `Product` that this action was bound to? You need the reference to _that_; if your class just creates a new instance and tries to remove the action for that, it won't work.

Comment: honestly, I didn't code this plugin, but based on the code, it seems so :)

Comment: _"This is code I tried"_ - so you are directly manipulating the plugin's code file then? (Must be, otherwise `$this` would not be pointing to the correct thing to begin with.) That is rather not a thing you should do, you will lose any of your modifications on the next plugin update. But this class appears to implement the singleton pattern, and the property is public - so you should be able to access it outside of the plugin context, using `Stock_status::instance()->stock_product`